# Overflow with CSS height:100%?

Tags: css

I have two `height: 100%;` boxes inside another div. But when I make the inside box `height: 100%;`, the green `<h2>` is moving over the red box. How can I solve this problem?

code: http://jsfiddle.net/ajnglagla/9yL7c946/

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqmQg.jpg

Comment: Well, that's exactly how `overflow:hidden` is _supposed_ to work - you get an element that is 100% high, and if the content exceeds that height it just _overflows_ the element, without influencing its effective height any more. If you don't want that - then don't use `overflow:hidden` ... maybe you just want to specify a minimum height instead ...?

Comment: I have tried overflow:hidden, but this doesnt solve my problem. I have 6 different height div boxes. I have wrote a small jquery to give them different heights but i am hoping to solve that problem with pure css @CBroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have best solution. try this

```css
.a-detay section {

  margin: 0 0 30px 0;

}

.a-detay section h2 {

  font-size: 190%;

  font-weight: normal;

  line-height: 1.15em;

  margin: 10px 0;

}

.a-detay section .k-konteyner {

  position: relative;

}

.a-detay section .k-konteyner .alanozet {

  padding: 10px;

  width: 134px;

  height: 100%;

  position: absolute;

  right: 0px;

  box-sizing: border-box;

  top: 0;

}

.a-detay section .k-konteyner .detay {

  padding: 30px;

  width: 100px;

}

.a-detay #guvenlik .k-konteyner {

  border: 5px solid #f7464a;

}

.a-detay #guvenlik .k-konteyner .alanozet {

  background-color: #f7464a;

}

.a-detay #guvenlik h2 {

  color: #f7464a;

}

.a-detay #saglik .k-konteyner {

  border: 5px solid #4eb055;

}

.a-detay #saglik .k-konteyner .alanozet {

  background-color: #4eb055;

}

.a-detay #saglik h2 {

  color: #4eb055;

}
```

```html
<section class="a-detay">
  <section id="guvenlik" class="konu">
    <h2>Red</h2>
    <div class="k-konteyner">
      <div class="detay">
        Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
      </div>
      <div class="alanozet">When i make this area height 100%, Green H2 is being over the RED box.</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="saglik" class="konu">
    <h2>Green</h2>
    <div class="k-konteyner">
      <div class="detay">
        Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
      </div>
      <div class="alanozet">When i make this area height 100%, Green H2 is being over the RED box.</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete `float: left;` in `a-detay section {}`

Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9yL7c946/2/)** *(Your JSFiddle)*

Why do you want to use **float** when you have 100% width?

Comment: Can you check this please? http://imgur.com/ZmGw20N It looks right but when i over the Green section on firebug, it shows highlighted area is still over the red box. If I over the red section it shows like that http://imgur.com/0RGDdhr

Comment: I will look in to it. Hang on.

Comment: Im sorry, can't figure it out, but i see that you use a lot of unnecessary `floats`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.a-detay {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.a-detay section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
.a-detay section h2 {
  font-size: 190%;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.15em;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.a-detay section .k-konteyner {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.a-detay section .k-konteyner .alanozet {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  width: 134px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.a-detay section .k-konteyner .detay {
  float: left;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 200px;
}
.a-detay #guvenlik .k-konteyner {
  border: 5px solid #f7464a;
}
.a-detay #guvenlik .k-konteyner .alanozet {
  background-color: #f7464a;
}
.a-detay #guvenlik h2 {
  color: #f7464a;
}
.a-detay #saglik .k-konteyner {
  border: 5px solid #4eb055;
}
.a-detay #saglik .k-konteyner .alanozet {
  background-color: #4eb055;
}
.a-detay #saglik h2 {
  color: #4eb055;
}
```

```html
<section class="a-detay">
  <section id="guvenlik" class="konu">
    <h2>Red</h2>
    <div class="k-konteyner">
      <div class="detay">
        Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
      </div>
      <div class="alanozet">
        When i make this area height 100%, Green H2 is being over the RED box.
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="saglik" class="konu">
    <h2>Green</h2>
    <div class="k-konteyner">
      <div class="detay">
        Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
        <br>Left
      </div>
      <div class="alanozet">
        When i make this area height 100%, Green H2 is being over the RED box.
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: it looks fine but when i mouseover i still see the hightlighted area is not over the div. This is really strange :/

Comment: can i change your structure ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  .a-detay #saglik h2 {margin-top:30px;color:#4eb055;}
```

modify the css rule like this. this will work i think.. but i don't know the method is correct or not

or this

```
    .a-detay section { float:left; width:100%; height:100%; box-sizing: border-box; margin:30px 0px 30px 0;}
```

Comment: it looks ok but when i mouse over i still see the hightlighted area is not over the div.